# Name resolution and Point of instantiation in Templates

Tags: c++, templates

This is the statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.6.4.1 Point of instantiation

```
 4.If a virtual function is implicitly instantiated, its point of instantiation
   is immediately following the point of instantiation of its enclosing
   class template specialization.

 5.An explicit instantiation directive is an instantiation point for the
   specialization or specializations specified by the explicit 
   instantiation directive.

 6.The instantiation context of an expression that depends on the
   template arguments is the set of declarations with external linkage 
   declared prior to the point of instantiation of the template 
   specialization in the same translation unit.
```

I am unable to write a programs for this whole section. I am trying to write a programs for this section from yesterday.

Please, normally I would try to ask a 1 or more points. In any section. But here I am unable to understand a single point in this section.

So, kindly can any one provide me a code for this sections to understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Templates :Name resolution:Point of instantiation: -->can any one tell some more examples for this statement? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810269/templates-name-resolutionpoint-of-instantiation-can-any-one-tell-some-more)

Comment: my eyes! please don't use all caps, it scares away people!

Comment: __This is not a duplicate__, though it looks similar. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810269/ BE Student asked for clarification regarding a different snippet from the standard. There's no reason to close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two statements explain where the instantiation point of certain template constructs are; it doesn't introduce new template constructs. So you can reuse your previous examples.

The third statement (14.6.4.1/6) tells us what the point of instantiation points is: they are the point where names are looked up during the second phase of name lookup. Names that are declared *before* the instantiation point are visible; those declared afterwards are not. (In the first phase of two-phase name lookup, non-dependent names are looked up in the set of declarations that precede the template *definition*).

So, given:

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
  T() + T();
}
```

the instantiation contexts of the expression `T()+T()` is the set of declarations that precede the respective instantiation points of `foo<T>`. The name `operator+` is looked up in those contexts, and includes declarations that follow this definition but precede the instantiation point.

Comment: There is a difference between "point of instantiation" and "instantiation context". The former is just a location within a translation unit. But the latter is a state/condition. "context" is always a state, and "point of" is always a location. For example "point of definition" specifies the location in a template definition (not necessarily at the time the template was defined - c.f. 14.6.4/1bullet1), "point of declaration" is the location at which a name starts to be visible. And "definition context" is the state that the TU was in at template-definition time (c.f. bullet2).

Comment: I had assumed there's no doubt about that, given that /6 defines how the two relate. If the two would have been synonyms, /6 would make no sense at all. With BE Student's questions, it's hard to keep your answers concise.

Answer (score 1):

There seems always tons of questions with regards to instantiation context.

The example given by MSalters is problematic:

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
  T() + T();
}
```

consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> void foo() {
  T() + T();
}

class A {};

void operator +(const A&, const A&)
{
    cout << "Called operator+(const A&, const A&)" <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<A>();
}
```

That compiles and runs on all compilers, but if you put the class A definition into a namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> void foo() {
    T() + T();
}

namespace {
   class A {};
}


void operator+(const A&, const  A&)
{
    cout << "operator+(const N::A&, const N::A&)" << endl;
}

int main()
{
     foo<A>();
}
```

Clang will fail to compile, but VC++ and gcc compiles. Why? which compiler conforms to the spec?

Frankly, I don't know. Some compiler, like gcc even contradicts itself in this area. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> void foo() {
    g(T());
}

namespace {
   class A {};
}


void g(A a)
{
    cout << "g(A)" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<A>();
}
```

Simply change from "operator+" to a function named "g", gcc fails to compile???Why???

If the Spec is correct, then why GCC cannot find 'g'?

> 6.The instantiation context of an expression that depends on the    template arguments is the set of declarations with external linkage
>   declared prior to the point of instantiation of the template
>   specialization in the same translation unit.

When I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition", 26.3.5 Template and Namespaces, he has this example:

```
namespace N{
    class A{};
    char f(A);
}

char f(int);

template<typename T>
char g(T t)
{
    return f(t);       //choose f() depending on what T is
}

char f(double);

char c1 = g(N::A());   //causes N::f(N::A) to be called
char c2 = g(2);        //causes f(int) to be called
char c3 = g(2.1);      //causes f(int) to be called, f(double) not considered
```

Here, f(t) is clearly dependent, so we cannot bind f at the point of definition. To generate a specialization for g(N::A), the compiler looks in namespace N for functions called f() and fins N::f(N::A).

The f(int) is found because it is in scope at the point of definition of the template. The f(double) is not found because it is not in scope at the point of definition of the template, and argument-dependent lookup does not find a global function takes only arguments of built-in types.

So it's a mess!