# Strange Template Behaviour

Tags: c++, templates

The following code does not compile.:-

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct B;

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    B<T> _a;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    A<T> _b;
};


int main()
{
    B<int> c;

    return 0;
}
```

From the first look the reason seams to be the circular dependency between A and B. However when instead of using type B _b member explicitly, the vector (storing the actual object and not pointer to it) is used. Like this

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct B;

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    std::vector<B<T>> _a;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    A<T> _b;
};


int main()
{
    A<int> c;

    return 0;
}
```

, everything is working fine. And the question is why? If vector needed only size of the B,T> structure so is any part of A in first example because it does not invoke any B's functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example the `sizeof(A<int>)` and `sizeof(B<int>)` are defined recursively.
Ask yourself: What is the `sizeof(A<int>)`?

You can't answer because `sizeof(A<int>)` depends on `sizeof(B<int>)` and recursively.

In the second example `sizeof(A<int>)` is `sizeof(std::vector<B<int>>)` which is constant, indeed `std::vector` does a heap allocation.

Try to replace `std::vector` by `std::array` and you'll have the same issue again. Indeed the size of `std::array` depends on the size of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector`'s implementation apparently only has pointers and/or references to `B<T>` as members. Since references and pointers to incomplete types are legal, the program compiles correctly.

Comment: I guess you are correct. However how for resizing logic of vector, copy should be implemented and for that the copy c'tor should be used and I guess you cannot invoke it on incomplete type. What else I really can cheat the compiler and instead of declaring member of type X I will define the vector with size 1 which will include the undefined type. I am very confused why it works.

Comment: The member functions of the vector are instantiated at a later point in the program than the main class definition. C++ has something called the "point of instantiation". See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810269/templates-name-resolutionpoint-of-instantiation-can-any-one-tell-some-more . This may help you understand how such code works.